# Get relations with conditions in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an app with .net core 2 and Entity Framework Core 2.

I have the following models:

```
Topic {
   int TopicID,
   List<Message> Messages,
   …
}

Message {
   int MessageID,
   int TopicID,
   Topic Topic,
   int UserID,
   User User,
   …
}

User {
   int UserID,
   …
}
```

I want to fetch all data for a topic and its relations, so that if I have a topic with 3 messages, each written by a different user, I would get the following object:

```
var topic = new Topic() {
   TopicID: 1,
   Messages: new Message[] {
      new Message() { MessageID: 1, TopicID: 1, UserID: 1, User: new User() { UserID: 1 } },
      new Message() { MessageID: 2, TopicID: 1, UserID: 2, User: new User() { UserID: 2 } },
      new Message() { MessageID: 3, TopicID: 1, UserID: 1, User: new User() { UserID: 3 } }
   }
}
```

This was simple and I did it with the following implementation:

```
return context.Topics
   .Include(t => t.Messages)
   .ThenInclude(m => m.User)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .SingleOrDefault(t => t.TopicID == topicId);
```

but now I want to add some conditions to the messages:

1. take only 2 messages at a time
2. pass a parameter indicating I want to take only messages where `messageID` is less than a given parameter

I checked and found out that `Include()` does not have the ability to use `Take()` and `Where()`, so I tried to implement this with `Select()`:

```
return context.Topics
   .Where(t => t.TopicID == topicId)
   .Select(t => new {
      TopicId = t.TopicID,
      Messages = t.Messages
         .Where(m => m.MessageID < messageId)
         .Take(2)
   })
   .AsNoTracking()
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

When I remove the `Where()` and `Take()` from inside the `Select()`, it works (but without the conditions I want to implement), but if I keep them, it returns errors:

> {System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dal.Models.Message]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dal.Models.Message] _ToEnumerable[Message](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dal.Models.Message])'Parameter name: arg0   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ProjectionExpressionVisitor.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression expression)   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, String callerName)   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.RelinqExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression expression)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.SelectClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel)   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, INodeTypeProvider nodeTypeProvider, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<Execute>b__0()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)   at Features.Topic.TopicMessagesQueries.getTopic(RbbContext context, Int32 entitiesFetchLimit, Int32 topicId) in TopicQueries.cs:line 20   at Features.Topic.TopicService.getTopic(RbbContext context, ITopicQueries topicQueries, Int32 topicId) in TopicService.cs:line 43   at Features.Topic.TopicController.Get(Int32 id) in TopicController.cs:line 34}

I also want to get the user relation from the messages, I tried adding another `Select()` inside `t.Messages`, but that also did not work.

I can't find similar references in google/stackoverflow of queries with 2-level relationships and conditions on the relationships.

Can anyone here can direct me to get this query right?

Comment: That's because you're selected an anonymous type.  Instead what you really should do is create a model that you populate and not let your entities leak out of your DAL.

Comment: hi @juharr thanks for your reply. i’m afraid i didn’t fully understand it, can you please explain your answer?

Comment: @shahaf when you use this `Select(t => new {` the query will return a anonymous type as you haven't specified a type after `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous type. You will have to project the final output to your `Topic` object. This might look a bit ugly, but it should hit the database just once and get just the required records. Do run a profiler to see the resulting query.

```
   return context.Topics
   .Where(t => t.TopicID == topicId)
   .Select(t => new {
                   TopicId = t.TopicID,
                   Messages = t.Messages
                               .Where(m => m.MessageID < messageId)
                               .Take(2)
           }).AsNoTracking()
             .AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Topic
                                  {
                                   TopicId = x.TopicId ,
                                   Bookings = x.Messages.ToList()
                                   }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: (1) why are you using ToList() after the first Select()? although the Messages are a list, the object itself that contains the messages is a single object. shouldn’t it be SingleOrDefault()?

Comment: (2) if i also want each message to contain its user how would i do that in your suggestion?

Comment: (1) Did you try to execute the code? If you remove the ToList, you won't be able to project to the `Topic` type.

Comment: (2) try using the `Include` after the Where clause, it should fetch the messages with User.

Comment: im not near the code to try it now, will do it later and inform you if it works;   regarding the Include() you suggested to get the user data - i read somewhere that Select disables all Includes, and that in ef core v2 for some reason it is possible to use Include inside Select so it could eigther be a bug or misinformation in the documentations. could this be done with another Select inside the messages Select?

Comment: It's better to use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` when you want to switch between DB and in memory to avoid creating an unnecessary intermediate list.